# Disable client certificate trust in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl-certificate

Is there a programatic way of disabling a client app's certificate trust in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [X509Certificate Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.aspx)

and maybe [X509Certificate2 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx)

Example;

```
using System;

using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


public class X509
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        // The path to the certificate.
        string Certificate = "Certificate.cer";

        // Load the certificate into an X509Certificate object.
        X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(Certificate);

        // Get the value.
        string resultsTrue = cert.ToString(true);

        // Display the value to the console.
        Console.WriteLine(resultsTrue);

        // Get the value.
        string resultsFalse = cert.ToString(false);

        // Display the value to the console.
        Console.WriteLine(resultsFalse);

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for input, would this work with a PFX certrificate in data transfer?